# parent div scaling to content inside it

Tags: html, css

I thought a parent div automatically scales according to the content inside it. 
For example I have a div as a parent inside that I have another div with just text in it. When I view it through firebug its showing the parent div stretches all the way across the browser. I thought it should only stretch to the length of the text inside the inner div. How can I make the parent scale to the inner and not the full browser width.

```
<div id="outter">
    <div id="inner">some empty text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By default divs are block level elements and span the full width of their containing elements.

Comment: You're right about divs scaling to their content automatically (without needing any css), but only vertically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the div inside the other will be as large as the div containing it.  So you must set the size of the div "outter" or by default it will be 100% of the document

Comment: Ah ok so by default it will be the browsers width in percent. So if I set the div to inline-block then this should fix the problem. Or set a width. I don't want to set a width because the text changes dynamically so it needs to adjust to the text size.

Comment: Yes i would set this to an inline black to solve this problem as it will expand the div as well

Answer (score 4):

An element which is `display:block` (which `div` is by default) by default is 100% width.  `display: inline` or `inline-block` elements will fit to their content.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` is a block element. try `<span>`, or `<div style="display:inline"></div>`...`<div style="float:left"></div>` might have a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that those divs are both:

```
display:block;
```

If you do:

```
#outer, #inner {
    display:inline;
}
```

Both elements will be only as wide as their content.

Answer (score 0):

You can also now have the width to be `fit-content`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content

The below code worked for me:

```
<div>
<div style={'width': 'fit-content'} >hello world</div>
</div>
```