# Firefox - Unnecessary x-scrollbar

Tags: css, firefox

An unwanted x-scrollbar appears in Firefox.
Even if disable it by `overflow-x: hidden;` the width is wrong (strings stay hidden).

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}
.left {
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.left > div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Any suggestions why?

jsfiddle to play with code: https://jsfiddle.net/5yqkoujm/

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
.left {
    max-height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 20px;  //this fixes scrollbar covering content
}
.left > div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

EDIT: For mozilla browser:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
.left {
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.left {
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-right: 20px;  //this fixes scrollbar covering content
}
}
.left > div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Then y-scrollbar is always visible :(

Comment: @holden321 In this case, try to set overflow-y: auto; again, and check if it works as you want it to do. Just change height or shorten the list to see it.

Comment: @holden321 Fixed it. See the comment.

Comment: The `padding-right` fixes the covering in FF but spoil view in Chrome.

Comment: @holden321 Now it should work fine. I have added style for mozilla.

Comment: Well, `padding-right` is "dirty" fix actually. But it seems there is no other.

Answer (score 1):

So, here is my guess : you need a fixed height and a dynamic width, adjusting to what's inside the left `div`.

> An element which is `display:block` (which `div` is by default) by default is 100% width. `display: inline` or `inline-block` elements will fit to their content.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896303/8932080

You should try this *EDITED* code :

*Another edit : now hides the scrollbar if there is not enough items to show. Last but not least edit, you got what you've asked :)*

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.left>div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block; /*Nailed it, here is the fix !*/
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div>Some not so long string</div>
    <div>Some not so long string</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long stringSome not so not stringSome not so not tringSome not sog stringSome not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
      <div>Some not so long string</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope it will help :)

---

Fix found thanks to this thread : [parent div scaling to content inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896276/parent-div-scaling-to-content-inside-it)

Comment: The author wants it to be scrollable, if the content goes outside the div. The container can have lots of text inside, it must not take the whole page.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze You need to have a fixed width but dynamic height ?

Comment: No, auto width and scrollable to y axis.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Edited to answer the question

Comment: The x-scrollbar is still here :)

Comment: Updated the code, again. Now it works fine to me, how about you ?

Comment: The y-scroll is always visible now. Which is not proper work.

Comment: @holden321 I'm pretty sure you'll find a workaround, maybe messing with auto properties :)

Comment: And here you go, hope you'll like this one, final version!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158939/discussion-between-youdeservethat-and-holden321).